# What is the expected length of an interval on an arc of a circle that can be constructed using exponential variates?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

I had asked this question on Math stackexchange once before and now again but this does not seem to be drawing too much attention. Since this is a question that can be safely classified as non-measure theoratic probability, I think this will get enough attention here.

Consider a circle $S$ of length $\theta$. Now suppose, we delete an interval $I$ of length $|I|$ (I'll drop the $|\cdot|$ notation for length and directly write $I$) from it.

Now on $S-I$, I choose a point $U$ uniformly at random and construct around $U$, another interval $J_{U}$ having it's length distributed as a $\min(J^{+}+J^{-}, \theta)$ where $J^{+}$ and $J^{-}$ are iid exponential$(1)$ variates.

**What is the expected length of this interval constructed**? i.e. what is $E(J_{U})?$

What I did was I considered one end  point of $I$ to be the origin(or the pole/reference point of the circle with coordinates measured in anticlockwise direction) and then it is equivalent to constructing $J$ around $0$ and the whole interval $I$ shifted anticlocklwise by $U$. Then $J^{+}$ can be considered to be measured in anticlockwise direction and $J^{-}$ to be measured in clockwise direction about $0$.

Using the above, we get $E\left(\min(U,J^{+})+\min(\theta-I-U,J^{-})\right)$.

Now by conditioning on $U=u$, \begin{align*}
    &U\int_{U}^{\infty}e^{-z}\,dz+\int_{0}^{U}ze^{-z}\,dz +(\theta-I-U)\int_{\theta-I-U}^{\infty}e^{-z}dz+\int_{0}^{\theta-I-U}ze^{-z}\\
    &=(1-e^{-U})+(1-e^{-(x-U)})\end{align*}

Now taking the expectation in $U$, we get $\frac{2x-2(1-e^{-x})}{x}$ where $x=\theta - I$ .

Is the above correct or am I missing some more terms?

Or even going a step backwards, is the conditional expectation of the length of $J_{u}$ given $U=u$ correct?

**i.e. if $u$ is a fixed point on $S-I$, then what is the expected length of an interval (distributed as $\min(J^{+}+J^{-},\theta)$ for iid expo$(1)$) that can be constructed about $U$ on the arc $S-I$**?

EDIT: I am now sure that I am missing more details. For example, what if $J^{+}>I+u$ and $\theta-J^{-}\leq J^{+}$, then I am certainly ending up ignoring some parts.

Can someone please help me with this.

Edit: **To be more explicit, in words, what I want to do is :- We are looking to find the expected length of the interval $I'$ that is built outside of $I$ when we imagine $I$ to be part of the original circle.**

This is the mental image I had while doing the problem
[image]

**EDIT** Additionally in the paper, the description given (**this was the initial question posted on mathstackexchange which attracted close votes for needing more details**) that if $I'$ is an independent interval(arc) having length law $\min(J^{+}+J^{-},\theta)$ built around $0$ and if $I$ is a fixed interval not containing $0$ then note the following definition $I\cap_{0} I'=\{x\in I': x\nleftrightarrow 0 \,\text{within}\, I'\setminus I\}$. Then $H_{0}(I):=E(I\cap_{0}I')$ and $UH_{0}=E(H_{0}(I-U))$ for an uniform $U$ variate on the circle.

It is this $UH_{0}$ and $E(UH_{0})$ that I want to calculate. It is also claimed later in the paper(page 23) that $E(H_{0}(I-u)|U=u)$ equals the expected length of part of the interval $I'$ outside $I^c$ that can be constructed around $U=u$

This is all the details I have.

Comment: By "length" of $S$, do you mean circumference?

Comment: @Eli Yes I mean circumference

Comment: I think by adding a figure or two you could help clear up some confusion to both this question and the identical one you asked 2 days ago at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780580/what-is-the-expected-length-of-an-interval-on-an-arc-of-a-circle-that-can-be-con.

Comment: Your question is unclear, because for any given point $U$ and length $L$ there are infinitely many intervals of length $L$ that satisfy the description "constructed around $U.$"

Comment: @JimB I'll try to post the mental image I had while doing the problem. This is what is claimed in pages 23 and 21 of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5705) paper(explicitly lemma 3.8). Since this question was not attracting any users in math stackexchange I decided to ask it here because this can be classified as a stat question too. I say it in the beginning of my problem